# How to pass an arguments which consists a path of a file in VB script?

Tags: vbscript

I am passing an argument to a .vbs file using bat file and the argument is a path to a folder.
And in the vb script i am reading the argument and wanted to use running on .exe file like below.

```
***var1 = Arg(0)
      msgbox "First parameter passed was " _
      & var1
WScript.Echo  var1
Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Exec("%var1%\Change SDMClient Installation.exe")***
```

But the last line is giving me error.

How can i resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

You should not use the %% rather concatenate the string like

```
  var1 = Wscript.Arguments(0)
  msgbox "First parameter passed was " _
  & var1


   WScript.Echo  var1
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    pathToExec = var1 & "\Change SDMClient Installation.exe"
    pathToExec = chr(34) & pathToExec & chr(34)
    wscript.echo pathToExec
    objShell.Exec(pathToExec)
```

Comment: It is giving error. WshShell.Exec: test.vbs(11, 3) WshShell.Exec: The system cannot find the file specified.

Dim objShell
Dim Arg, var1
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
var1 = Arg(0)
msgbox "First parameter passed was " _
       & var1
WScript.Echo  var1
Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
  pathToExec = var1 & "\Change SDMClient Installation.exe"
  objShell.Exec(pathToExec)

Comment: You pass the relative path of the directory to the argument and it will use that as parent directory and within the directory it will launch `Change SDMClient Installation.exe`. For example, lets say your file is located in `C:\Users\your_user\Desktop\Change SDMClient Installation.exe` and you pass argument as `C:\Users\your_user\Desktop` , this script will assume that argument as a directory and it will launch the program inside that . Notice the line `pathToExec = var1 & "\Change SDMClient Installation.exe"`. You let me know the exact path , i will help you more.

Comment: start "" "C:\Users\skasturi\OneDrive - Avaya\Desktop\test.vbs" C:\Backup\SDM\_CompanySDMClient_installation

I am passing this path (C:\Backup\SDM\_CompanySDMClient_installation) as an arugument for my vb script. C:\Backup\SDM\_CompanySDMClient_installation and the Change SDMClient Installation.exe is inside this folder.

Comment: I tested in my machine and it is working fine. Make sure you pass a string as arugment like this `start "C:\Users\skasturi\OneDrive - Avaya\Desktop\test.vbs" "C:\Backup\SDM_CompanySDMClient_installation"` . In essence all the script does is whatever you pass as argument it will use that as a folder and execute `Change SDMClient Installation.exe` inside of that folder. Hope this helps if so please mark this as answer.

Comment: Output from my bat file.
start "" "C:\Users\skasturi\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\test.vbs" "C:\Backup\SDM\_SDMClient_installation"
)  else (echo Proceeding with installation of sdm client )
Program Found

This statement in my vbs file WScript.Echo  var1 is showing the path which is not in double quotes - WScript.Echo  var1 - C:\Backup\SDM\_SDMClient_installation -

Comment: Yes that is fine because it will echo the value and it is ok if not inside quotes , if you want double quotes i've update the answer . Check it